# Choosing Python3.3 interpreter in Eclipse problems

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, settings, pydev, interpreter

I am new to Eclipse & PyDev (on Ubuntu 13.04) and want to try Python3.3 programming.
But I cannot choose python3.3 iterpreter, - I try to choose it in usr\lib\python3.3 , but:
- when I try to choose PYTHONPATH by clicking "New folder" - window doesn't open (I can do it onl after choosing auto-config, which will add python2.7 pates);
- I don't know the file in usr\lib\python3.3, which I need to choose, as python3.3 interpreter (auto-config returns me only 2.7 objects).

Can you advice me how to choose python3.3 interpreter (maybe the main is the file\path I need to choose in " usr\lib\python3.3" as interpreter file - in windows Eclipse I see python3.3.exe, - I need to find its equal in Ubuntu I think)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the auto-config option. It will automatically find the libraries.

Comment: If auto-config doesn't work, you need to manually find the objects. Try searching where you installed Python.

Answer (score 0):

You set the path `usr\lib\python3.3` by typing it directly in the 'Interpreter Executable' field! You don't have to search for the Interpreter file. This will do the Auto Config for you. Afterwards you declare a name and you're done.